# Streaming audio/video through Node.js and Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, streaming

Using Node.js and Socket.io, I would like to stream a continuous audio/video feed from the client, via the server and to the other clients, where the server is the mediator.

A code example with an explanation would be great. It should demonstrate:

1. How to capture audio/video on the client side
2. How to stream that data to the server
3. How the server should deal with that data, and forward it to other clients
4. How those clients would be able to play/display that data

Thank you!

Comment: https://obsproject.com/ + http://twitch.tv

Comment: @Sunshine I need to know how to do this in HTML/JavaScript/Node.js/Socket.io.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WEB RTC](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/) for your purposes. 
But browsers [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=webrtc) isnt very good.

Comment: WebRTC isn't the solution for me. One client broadcasts to many, so the stream must travel via the server.

Comment: And you cannot broadcast to sever than to other clients? This the only way to use video capturing with js.

Comment: WebRTC is very experimental and has limited browser support, as you said, so this solution isn't great. I've actually solved the video issue, but I still need to work out how to stream audio via Socket.io